# Excel: How to find the first row's value of a column depending on where to find a given number in another row of the same column

Tags: excel

Imagine a 100x100 table. I have to find a given value in the first column. Then I have to check the row contains that given value, and I have to find the column where the value is 1 (every row has only one cell with value 1), and I need the first row's value of that column. I've tried several lookup functions (vlookup, hlookup, index match match, etc). No results. Is it possible using only functions and no VBA at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to use `INDEX` rather than `INDIRECT`, it's not volatile and it's more robust in dealing with added rows or columns than "hardcoded" values like "B" and "D", so assuming data in `A1:Z100` you can use this formula for the match, assuming a search value of "x"

`=MATCH(1,INDEX(B2:Z100,MATCH("x",A2:A100,0),0),0)`

...and you can add an extra INDEX function to retrieve the first row value for that column

`=INDEX(B1:Z1,MATCH(1,INDEX(B2:Z100,MATCH("x",A2:A100,0),0),0))`

Comment: +1 - Funny thing is, I was thinking to myself, "how would barry do it" when coming up with my answer :-)  I'm still trying to learn from the best!